# Can any one let me know how to override Tab open method

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

While opening a tab 
    `Ti.Ui.Tab.open(win);`
would like to do some work. I have tried like this
   `tabcomponent.open = function(win){
     // Code goes here
 };`

but haven't worked. Can anyone let me know how to override a method.

Thanks in advance,

Swathi.

Answer (score 3):

You can't override the default functions. Extend your tabcomponent with a custom function that doesn't have the same name as the default functions.

```
tabcomponent.openTab = function(win){
     // Code goes here
 };
```